# Finding points on a line

Tags: image, algorithm, math

(This question could be better off on math, but im not sure)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujPJG.png

This is probably very simple but the way I'm thinking of doing it doesn't seem very easy and there must be a simpler method.I've got an image and I want to find some points that fall on a line so in this example image below the starting point of my line is (39,75) and the ending point is (75,142) from there I want to find 5 points (or any number really 5 is just an example) that are all on that line.

Is there some equation I can use that will get me a certain amount of points given any start and end coordinates?

Comment: This is (really) a pure math question, but I'm glad you were able to get an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Your line segment can be described by this equation:

```
x = 39 + t * (75 - 39)
y = 75 + t * (142 - 75)
```

where, t can take on any value between 0 and 1.

So, to get random points on the line, just choose a random value for t (between 0 and 1), and calculate what x, y are.

The idea is, x is traveling from 39 to 75, while y is traveling from 75 to 142, and t represents the fraction of travel that has been completed.

Answer (score 3):

yes.

suppose (x0,y0) and (x1,y1) are the starting and ending points on the line.

t*(x0,y0) + (t-1)*(x1,y1) are also going to be points on that line where t ranges from 0 to 1.

note:

if t = 0, you get (x0,y0)

if t = 1, you get (x1,y1)

if t is any value inside (0,1) you get that "percentage" of the way from (x0,y0) to (x1,y1)

(if t = 0.5, you are halfway between the points)

this is what is often called "tweening" in computer graphics

Answer (score 0):

A line can be defined by the function `y = mx + b` where x and y are coordinates on the cartesian plane, m is the slope of the line defined by `(y2 - y1)/(x2 - x1)`, and b is the point where the line intersects the y-axis.

Given that information and two points on the line, you can fill in the blanks with some basic algebra to determine a function that defines the line.  Note that if your coordinate plane for the image places (0, 0) in the top left corner, you may have to flip the sign of the y-coordinate.

Comment: The problem with slope-intercept form is that it doesn't deal well with vertical lines.

Comment: Though it's trivial to special-case it.

Comment: @Greg Of course. But I lost the count of the bugs I found due to forgetting it.